# Change css of div when ajax return success

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I have 3 buttons which visibility is hidden. When I click my button which function is added, it will run through my Ajax call, inside my Ajax success I count if the table rows are > 0 just like this:

```
  $('#addRefBtn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var get_input = $('#qr_ref').val();
    var get_po = $('#get_po').val();
    //location.reload();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'validate_qr.php',
        data: {
          qr_code:get_input,
          po_ID: get_po
        },
        success: function(result)
        {
          var rowCount = $('#productSalesTable tbody tr.ps').length;
          // var promo = $('#promoModal');
          // var remove = $('#removeModal');
          // var confirm = $('#confirmModal');
          // console.log(rowCount);
          if(rowCount > 0)
          {
            $('#promoModal').css('visibility', 'visible');
            $('#removeModal').css('visibility', 'visible');
            $('#confirmModal').css('visibility', 'visible');
          }
          else
          {
            $('#promoModal').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            $('#removeModal').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            $('#confirmModal').css('visibility', 'hidden');
          }
        }
      });
  });
```

I comment the `location.reload()` in order for me to see if the button change its *css* and the answer is yes. It shows when the table is > 0.

My main concern is when I reload the page, it's back to its original style which is `style='visibility:hidden;'`

This is my HTML

```
                    <div id='promoModal' style='visibility:hidden;'>
                    <button type="button" class='btn btn-block btn-primary btn-flat' id="promo_modal" data-poid="<?php echo $_GET['po_ID'];?>">
                      Add Promo
                    </button>
                </div>

                  <div id='removeModal' style='visibility:hidden;'>
                    <input type="button" class='btn btn-block btn-warning btn-flat' id="remove_modal"value="Remove Item">
                  </div>

                  <!-- <div><button type="button" class='btn btn-block btn-danger btn-flat' id="void_modal">Void Transaction</button></div> -->
                  <div id='confirmModal' style='visibility:hidden;'>
                    <button type="button" class='btn btn-block btn-success btn-flat' id="confirm_modal" data-id="<?php echo $_GET['po_ID'];?>">   Confirm Transaction
                    </button>
                  </div>
```

It's kinda weird because I knew that my code works, but it doesn't change the style, even if the table's length is > 0.

I'm looking forward for some suggestions or comments.

Your time is appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: try display:none and display:inline

Comment: use `toggleClass` first use class like `visible` and use in div. once ajax completed use `toggleClass` like `$( "#removeModal" ).toggleClass( "hide" )`

Comment: Why would you reload the page?

Comment: @PimH I already tried that but it's not properly working as per my expected result.

Comment: @connexo I reload the page if it success or not. It shows a message. Reloading a page indicates if the action is success or not. If input is valid or not.

Comment: @ShivKumarBaghel what do you mean by that? I am not familiar with that approach.

Comment: You're almost certainly doing it wrong then.

Comment: What do you mean? Im just adding some validation in my project. It's working properly with my functions. I just want to hide the buttons if table values shows a success or an error. If success, the button will show. If not, a session error message will show. Just like that.

Comment: If you're using reload, you will have to do the changes on the serverside.

Comment: My concern is that, when I don't reload the page and the table length is > 0 it changes it css property. But when I reload the page it doesn't show anymore.

Comment: Reloading the page restores the pre-ajax-call state, as if the user comes to the page for the very first time.

Comment: Is there no other way to alter this approach? @connexo

Comment: You don't use the 'result' from Ajax call, you're checking the old value.

Comment: That's an architectural thing. Any changes done by Javascript are completely gone and lost when reload occurs.

Comment: @PoulBak I just remove the result parameter in success. Its my JSON and it doesn't have any affiliation in my concern. Im sorry. It's just that. I want to change my css if it's a success call.

Comment: Reloading of page resets the data (it is a fresh page again!). You need to persist the change somewhere like in queryParams, cookies, localStorage etc..

Comment: @Mr_Green Hello sir! I am new with this and I am not familiar with using cookie, queryParams and etc. I just simply knew that If my ajax return success css property will change as much as how I want it to be.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to just remove the inline styles i.e `visibility: hidden` from the elements and apply the same style dynamically by checking the count of rows as you did in above code. You need to call that functionality twice.

Comment: Yes you're correct. That's what I intended to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to just call the success functionality twice. Here is the code, just to give you glimpse.

```
// Calling the hiding of rows functionality initially,
// to check whether the rows are 0 or more
// and applying styles as needed
successFunction();     // IMPORTANT!!!!

$('#addRefBtn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var get_input = $('#qr_ref').val();
  var get_po = $('#get_po').val();
  //
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'validate_qr.php',
    data: {
      qr_code: get_input,
      po_ID: get_po
    },
    success: function(result) {
      // re-paint or re-render the DOM element? (I am not sure what you want to do here)
      //
      // Applying the styles or calling the same function to re-apply the styles        
      successFunction();

      // reload the page. (The gist of using AJAX will be lost if you reload the page)
      // [ADVICE] Instead of reloading, I suggest you to render the DOM elements
      // If you are doing the render of DOM elements, then call the above successFunction after the rendering code.
      location.reload();
    }
  });
});

function successFunction() {
  var rowCount = $('#productSalesTable tbody tr.ps').length;
  if (rowCount > 0) {
    $('#promoModal').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('#removeModal').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('#confirmModal').css('visibility', 'visible');
  } else {
    $('#promoModal').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('#removeModal').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('#confirmModal').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello! I just reapply my idea with yours and its work conditionally. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Good to hear. Do keep exploring!

Answer (score 0):

below code is example of show hide div using `toggleClass` so after ajax call success use class to show hide.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#addRefBtn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('sss');  $('#removeModal').toggleClass('show');  
    }, 3000);
  });
  
  
});
```

```css
#removeModal {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='promoModal' style='visibility:hidden;'>
  <button type="button" class='btn btn-block btn-primary btn-flat' id="promo_modal" data-poid="<?php echo $_GET['po_ID'];?>">
      Add Promo
  </button>
</div>

<div id='removeModal'>
  <input type="button" class='btn btn-block btn-warning btn-flat' id="remove_modal" value="Remove Item">
</div>

<!-- <div><button type="button" class='btn btn-block btn-danger btn-flat' id="void_modal">Void Transaction</button></div> -->
<div id='confirmModal' style='visibility:hidden;'>
  <button type="button" class='btn btn-block btn-success btn-flat' id="confirm_modal" data-id="<?php echo $_GET['po_ID'];?>">   
    Confirm Transaction
  </button>
</div>


 <button type="button" class='btn btn-block btn-success btn-flat' id="addRefBtn">   
    Call Ajax Request
  </button>
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Can you please elaborate it for me? I'm sorry.

Comment: I already tried and understand your approach and it has a same function on what I have right now, it will show but when I reload the page it go back to its display:none again.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a class with display hide like as

```
.display-hide{
display:none;
}
```

change by default HTML by adding this class

```
<div id='promoModal' class="display-hide">
                    <button type="button" class='btn btn-block btn-primary btn-flat' id="promo_modal" data-poid="<?php echo $_GET['po_ID'];?>">
                      Add Promo
                    </button>
                </div>
```

and change response to

```
if(rowCount > 0)
          {
            $('#promoModal').show();
            $('#removeModal').show();
            $('#confirmModal').show();
          }
```

Comment: Hey there! Welcome. you can also do like `$("#promoModal, #removeModal, #confirmModal")` or add a same class to all three elements and do like `$(".modal").show()`. Also, it is always good to add descriptive answers :)

Comment: Hello! I appreciate your effort to view my post and give me some answers about my concern. But your approach has the same function as what I have right now. But anyway, thanks for your time and effort to view my post. Regards!